# Spring org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException exception

Tags: java, spring, exception

Could someone say why I am getting this exception ?
And how to solve the problem ?

If I understand correctly com.test.dao.CustomerDAO$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$ae49026e_3 class generated at runtime by spring.

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'com.test.dao.CustomerDAO$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$ae49026e_3' to required type 'com.test.dao.CustomerDAO'

Comment: Please elaborate on your question by telling us what you are trying to do, what code you are using(and have written) what you have tried already to remedy the problem. Doing so will help us help you.